# Unable to replace string with back slash characters

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I'm trying to trying to replace a "**\n**" to be replaced as "**\\n**"

i tried to convert the backslash as ascii code but still doesn't replace the string.

Here's my code

```
            var str = item.NotesContent;
            var repStr = str.replace(/\n/g, "\\n");
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The result seems fine. What is the problem? If you can see `\\` then it's working. An example of the desired result will be much helpful.

Comment: Your regex with `\n` is not matching backslashes at all: the backslash escapes the "n" to make a newline character. Where you show "original string" in your question, is that one single string that goes over four lines, or four separate strings printed one after the other? (Either way the "new string here" result shown doesn't make sense.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this you wanted?
Just escape \n with \. one slash escapes \ and other slash escapes \ \n's \

```js
 var str = "\n this is new string \n"
var repStr = str.replace(/\n+/g, "\\\\n");
console.log(repStr);
```